# Same citation in multiple paragraphs (undergrad paper)

Tags: citations, citation-style

What I currently have is:

`paragraph 1`

`paragraph 2`

`paragraph 3` [1].

With that I want to show that I am citing all 3 paragraphs from the same source. But appearently this is not right. Is it enough that I do?

`paragraph 1` [1]

`paragraph 2` [1]

`paragraph 3` [1].

Comment: You need to follow the citation style your professor specified. Also, I think your question is defined wrong compared to your question title. You are not citing the same source in multiple paragraphs. You are including a multiple paragraph, inline quote. Your title's answer is already on this site (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125537/citing-a-reference-multiple-times) and your other question seems to answered here https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/how-do-i-appropriately-use-inline-citations-for-multiple-quoted-paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

How about, assuming that [1] was written by Smith:

Smith notes, that ....... [1, p. 42]

Furthermore, Smith asserts that .... [1, p. 13]

Smith is also of the opinion that .... [1, p. 92]

You want to give the EXACT reference so that your reader can find it. And you want to clearly mark what is from you and what is from Smith. It goes without saying that the text in your paragraphs MUST be in your own words and not copied from Smith. Otherwise you need quotation marks.